# Regex: Matches a multi-line pattern until the same one occurs again

Tags: regex

I need to match 3 parts in the following bit:

```
# [1.3.3] (2019-04-16)

### Blah
* Loreum ipsum

# [1.3.0] (2019-04-01)

### Foo
* Loreum ipsum

# [1.2.0] (2019-03-05)

### Foo
* Loreum ipsum
```

Basically the first one would be

```
    # [1.3.3] (2019-04-16)

    ### Blah
    * Loreum ipsum
```

and so on.

I tried the following:

```
(# \[.*\] \([0-9\-]{10}\)(\n|.)*)
```

But that basically would go on to match the whole document. I need to tell him to stop matching until a new line start with `(# \[)` (what would be `^(?!(# \[)).*$`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the first part of your pattern to match the first line and then use a negative lookahead `(?!# )` to match the following lines if they don't start with `#` followed by a space:

```
^# \[[^]]+\] \([\d-]{10}\)\n(?:(?!# ).*(?:\n|$))*
```

About the pattern

- `^#` Start of string followd by `#` and space
- `\[[^]]+\]` Match from opening till closing square bracket using a negated character class
- `\([\d-]{10}\)\n` Match opening parenthesis then match 10 times what is listed in the character class followed by a closing parenthesis and a newline
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!# )` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not # and a space
  - `.*(?:\n|$)` Match any char except newline and match either a newline or assert end of the string
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vfwrDV/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
(# \[.*\] \([0-9\-]{10}\)(\n|[^#]|###)*)`
```

This will match any text until the next hash (except if that hash is part of a group of three hashes `###`) .

If you need to modify it for a varying number of hashes (strictly superior to 1), you could use

```
(# \[.*\] \([0-9\-]{10}\)(\n|[^#]|##+)*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^\#\s+\[.+?(?=^\#\s+\[|\Z)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/vr6Izq/1/) and mind the modifiers (`singleline` and `multiline`, `s` and `m`).

---

Broken down this is

```
^\#\s+\[     # start of the line, followed by "# ["
.+?          # everything else afterwards until ...
(?=
    ^\#\s+\[ # ... the pattern from above right at the start of a new line
    |        # or
    \Z       # the very end of the string
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to go would be:

```
^#.*(\r?\n(?!# ).*)+
```

To make it more precise:

```
^# \[\d.*(?:\r?\n(?!# ).*)+
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/8l59ZA/1)